# Custom dialog derived from wxDialog does not have close button and cannot be moved on windows

Tags: wxwidgets

In my wxWidget app, I have a custom dialog derived from wxDialog. The custom dialog basically works. When I run the app on MacOS, the custom dialog has a close button and can be moved around on the screen with the mouse. But on Windows 10 (with wxWidgets 3.2.2.1), the custom dialog does not have a close button and cannot be moved around with the mouse. I have google'd and tried other samples, but have not found a fix. How can I fix this problem?

This is my header file

```
class DlgDisplayLogs : public wxDialog
{
    public:
    DlgDisplayLogs(wxWindow* parent, const wxString& title);
    int insertPage(wxString caption, wxString hostname, wxArrayString strArray);
    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
    void onCopyClipboardClicked(wxCommandEvent& event);

    private:
    wxWindow*   parent;
    wxNotebook* notebook;
    DlgDisplayLogs* aham;
};
```

This is the .cpp file

```
DlgDisplayLogs::DlgDisplayLogs(wxWindow* parent, const wxString & title)
       : wxDialog(parent, -1, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600),
       wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxMINIMIZE_BOX | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX)
{
    this->parent = parent;

    Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, &DlgDisplayLogs::OnClose, this);

    notebook = new wxNotebook();
    notebook->Create(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
}
```

And this is how I create and launch the custom dialog

```
dlgDisplayLogs = new DlgDisplayLogs(this, "System log");
dlgDisplayLogs->Show();
```

Comment: why do you want to have a non-modal dialog there? Also did you try the dialogs sample?

Comment: I need both windows to be active at the same time, hence I'm using non-modal dialog. If I remove the wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxMINIMIZE_BOX | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX from the constructor, then it works fine except that it does not give me the option to resize the dialog. If I add just wxRESIZE_BORDER to the constructor, then once again the dialog cannot be moved and there is no close button. The dialog sample non-modal box also is not resizable and adding wxRESIZE_BORDER results in the same problem.

Comment: then this is a native behavior. But I dont understand your first comment. Are you saying thee are 2 dialogs at the same time and they have some kind of conflict? Please ellaborate.

Comment: There is one main window and at the same time there is a non-modal dialog. Under some cases, both need to be open at the same time, and this part works fine. The issue is that under Windows the non-modal dialog behaves very differently than it does under Mac. On Mac, it works exactly as expected. On Windows, the non-modal dialog cannot be resized.

Comment: why do you need a non-modal dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wxCAPTION` style to show the title bar under MSW.

Arguably, wxMSW shouldn't require it if any of `wxXXX_BOX` styles are specified, and I've created a PR to [change this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/23575), but in the meanwhile just adding `wxCAPTION` is a simple enough workaround.

Comment: with wxCAPTION, the window does not have a close button and it cannot be resized.

Comment: You need `wxCAPTION` _in addition_ to the other styles, not instead of them.